# Docker won't build a node container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a Docker image which contain a Node container (you can check the [code here](https://github.com/Axiol/Docker-for-Drupal-Vue.JS))

And when I run a `docker compose up -d`, I'm welcomed with this error

```
Building node
Step 1/2 : FROM node:latest
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:57055->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

I'm running Docker for Windows with Hyper-V and the diagnostic ID is EC5B82D9-E059-45C4-A909-C7A062429C98/2017-09-20_22-51-57 if you want to check it.

Anybody would have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 manually in the docker settings.

```
$ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today (with dial tcp)
A reinstallation of docker did the trick.